# Using AutoAugment and Cutout for CIFAR100

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, data-augmentation

I've been training the cifar 100 dataset on my own implementation of googlenet. I achieved around 71% top-1 accuracy in 200 epochs at first, then I boosted that to 78.5% with warmup training, sgd with nesterov momentum, and learning rate scheduling.

I've also been using some standard augmentations like padding with 4 zeros, 32x32 random crop, random horizontal flip and rgb channel normalizations.

Now I wish to see if I can further boost that accuracy to 79-80 or even beyond 80% using more augmentation techniques. My questions are:

1) Can I apply Cutout along with the standard augmentations I mentioned earlier? Or are they mutually exclusive?

2) Autoaugment apparently finds the 'best' augmentation policies for a dataset. If I apply autoaugment, do I still need to use cutout and my earlier augmentations? Or can all of them be used together?

3) I've been training 200 epochs (with batchsize 128) since I've seen it being done several times in various papers, and in my own implementations there is no significant improvement in training past 200 epochs. After applying cutout and/or autoaugment, should I train more epochs than 200? My learning rate starts at 0.1,  and decreases in the 60,120,160th epoch (with a decreasing factor of 0.2). Should I add more learning rate milestones and train up to 300 epochs?